# How to test the CPU, GPU, RAM utilization of the given Android app accurately?

Tags: android

I want to measure an app's accurate CPU, GPU, RAM utilization on Android phone. How can I achieve this goal? Is there any methods to read some information from Android system file? Any tutorial or advice will be very appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom layer of Android is a distribution of Linux. Hence, you can get information from "/proc/cpuinfo"
Below is an example:

```
String filePath = "/proc/meminfo";
FileReader localFileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(localFileReader, 8192);
String ret = localBufferedReader.readLine();
Log.i("Infor:", ret);
```

Second approach: Call linux commands:

```
 String pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
   Process process;
   String[] cmd = {
      "sh",
      "-c",
      "top -m 1000 -d 1 -n 1 | grep \""+pid+"\" "};
   process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
   String line = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: I want to get the information for a specific app. This method is about the whole processes. :(

Comment: @Ziyi, you can call Linux commands as the second approach. I edited my answer adding an example of using "top" command of Linux. You can call other commands in a similar way.